# Can I use one stored procedure to insert values into two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

How can I insert values into two different tables from the same stored procedure?

Comment: yes you can, and about how kindly do some search atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yup, easily:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InserIntoTwoTables]
    @arg1 INT, 
    @arg2 INT,
    @arg3 INT, 
    @arg4 INT
AS
BEGIN


    INSERT INTO Table1 (col1 ,col2)
    VALUES (@arg1 , @arg2) 

    INSERT INTO Table2 (col3 ,col4)
    VALUES (@arg3 , @arg4) 



END
GO
```

Frankly, it does not get anymore straightforward than that...

Comment: Thanks a lot.It was very helpful.I'm new in sql server and each time I missed the declaration of the data type after @arg. So I was getting error message repeatedly.

Comment: @Mimi I'm Happy to hear this was helpful. If any of the answers helped you to resolve the issue you were experiencing, please consider to mark an answer as accepted. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

That is the point of a Stored Procedure. Here is an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE <Procedure_Name, sysname, ProcedureName> 
    @Param1 INT, 
    @Param2 INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO TAB1
        (COL1)
    VALUES
        (@Param1)

    INSERT INTO TAB2
        (COL1)
    VALUES
        (@Param2)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes your code:

```
create or replace procedure insert_data()
as
begin
   insert into table1 values("a","b",100);
   insert into table2 values("a1","b1",1001);
end
```